# How to add n rows (not a single row) in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have some dataframes and i want to add some empty rows in each one. The number of the added empty rows depend of the lenght of maxdf minus the lenght of the dataframe itself.
I tried this code:

```
control1.loc[control1.index.max() + (len(maxdf)-len(control1))] = None
control2.loc[control2.index.max() + (len(maxdf)-len(control2))] = None
control3.loc[control3.index.max() + (len(maxdf)-len(control3))] = None
control4.loc[control4.index.max() + (len(maxdf)-len(control4))] = None
control5.loc[control5.index.max() + (len(maxdf)-len(control5))] = None
```

But it only adds one empty row in each df. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add `n` empty rows - you can do:

```py
n=10
control1=control1.append(pd.DataFrame([[None]*len(control1.columns)]*n, columns=control1.columns, index=np.arange(n)+control1.index.max()+1))
```

Using @Raphaele Adjerad sample data output:

```py
# Before:

     A    B    C    D
0  510  365  382  322
1  988   98  742   17
2  595  106  123  569

# After:

       A     B     C     D
0    510   365   382   322
1    988    98   742    17
2    595   106   123   569
3   None  None  None  None
4   None  None  None  None
5   None  None  None  None
6   None  None  None  None
7   None  None  None  None
8   None  None  None  None
9   None  None  None  None
10  None  None  None  None
11  None  None  None  None
12  None  None  None  None
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion, to use `concat` to append a DataFrame of the desired shape to your `control1` (same method for the other dataframes). Since there was no sample data, I created an example for `control1` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
control1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000,size=(3, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
maxdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 1000,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))


control1 = (pd.concat([control1, pd.DataFrame(np.nan, columns=control1.columns,
                                             index=range(0, maxdf.shape[0]-control1.shape[0]))])
              .reset_index(drop=True))
```

The output is :

```
      A      B      C      D
0  510.0  365.0  382.0  322.0
1  988.0   98.0  742.0   17.0
2  595.0  106.0  123.0  569.0
3    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
4    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Hope it helps